# Using jQuery or javascript to render json into multi-column table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to render a JSON into a HTML table. But the difficulty is making it so it loops through JSON and renders multiple columns if necessary.

For the example below, what I want is this:

Result wanted

**Result Wanted**

```
<table>
<tr><th>AppName</th><td>App 1</td><td>App 2</td></tr>
<tr><th>Last Modified</th><td>10/1/2012</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><th>App Logo</th><td>10/1/2012</td><td></td></tr>
blahblah
</table>

<table>
<tr><th>AppName</th><td>App 1</td></tr>
blahblah
</table>
```

**JSON Example**

```
"Records": [
    {
        "AppName": "App 1",
        "LastModified": "10/1/2012, 9:30AM",
        "ShipTo_Name": "Dan North",
        "ShipTo_Address": "Dan North",
        "ShipTo_Terms": "Dan North",
        "ShipTo_DueDate": "Dan North",
        "Items 1": [
            {
                "Item_Name": "Repairs",
                "Item_Description": "Repair Work"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AppName": "App 2",
        "AppLogo": "http://www.google.com/logo.png",
        "LastModified": "10/1/2012, 9:30AM",
        "BillTo_Name": "Steve North",
        "Items 1": [
            {
                "Item_Name": "Repairs",
                "Item_Description": "Repair Work"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"Records": [
    {
        "AppName": "App 1",
        "LastModified": "10/1/2012, 9:30AM",
        "ShipTo_Name": "222",
        "ShipTo_Address": "333 ",
        "ShipTo_Terms": "444",
        "ShipTo_DueDate": "5555",
        "Items 1": [
            {
                "Item_Name": "Repairs",
                "Item_Description": "Repair Work"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Code I am using now

```
function CreateComparisonTable (arr,level,k) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if(!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding = "--";

    if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects
        for (var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];
            if (typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                if(item !=0) {
                    dumped_text += '<tr><td>' + item + '<br>';
                    dumped_text += CreateComparisonTable(value,level+1);
                    dumped_text += '</td></tr>';
                } else {
                    dumped_text += CreateComparisonTable(value,level, value.length);
                }
            } else {
              dumped_text += '<tr><td>' + level_padding + item + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    } 
    return dumped_text;
}
```

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dUQQx/)

Comment: So, what have you tried? You can use `for (i in obj) { ... }` to loop through your object.

Comment: the first thing you need is to use different keys for each table array. you are using "Record" for both. Also, is there a reason you can't use JSON.parse?

Comment: Hi, how would JSON.parse help in this? Curious to learn more about this.

Answer (score 1):

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/), a plug-in for jQuery, is a good candidate for this scenario, and it's got a lot of features "baked into" its code.

I've used it, and it handled just about everything I threw at it.

Comment: DataTable is by far a great tool for all tables / ajax / jQuery related work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using a templating language such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html)

You might find this question useful: [How to structure JSON and build HTML via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375035/how-to-structure-json-and-build-html-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend jtemplates. a jQuery plugin http://jtemplates.tpython.com/ It's a powerful template language and the code can be stored anywhere. Inline in the page, in a separate file wherever is best for you. It looks a lot like asp classic.
Take a look

```
{#template MAIN}
 <div id="header">{$T.name}</div>
 <table>
 {#foreach $T.table as r}
  {#include row root=$T.r}
 {#/for}
 </table>
{#/template MAIN}

{#template row}
 <tr bgcolor="{#cycle values=['#AAAAEE','#CCCCFF']}">
  <td>{$T.name.bold()}</td>
  <td>{$T.age}</td>
  <td>{$T.mail.link('mailto:'+$T.mail)}</td>
 </tr>
{#/template row}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this comparison chart on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/Ju8ME/) I've just made. The individual cells are populated dynamically when the select event is detected from the dropdown menu. Maybe you can fork the fiddle and use some of the code to acomplish what you want to do with your table.