# Calculate One's Age Based on Date-of-Birth Info in JSON Array using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I was wondering how I could use PHP to calculate one's age given a date string with values from a JSON array:

```
{  
    "DOB":{ // should I use integers or strings for these values? I'm assuming strings for now.  
        "year": "1970",  
        "month": "01",  
        "day": "01"  
    }  
}
```

How would I then use PHP to calculate the age?
Additionally, say all of this information is a small part of something like a staff directory, with the format of `{ "People":{ "user1":{ label: value },"user2":{ label: value} } }`. How could I use PHP to create `<label>` tags for *label* within `<li>` tags for *value* (`<li><label>label</label>value</li>`) within unordered lists for each *user* within **divs** for each user?
***Please*** tell me if this is confusing; and the calculation of the age is my highest priority right now.

Comment: well with php you would be using each of those values as arguments in mktime() to create a timestamp and then you would subtract that timestamp from the current timestamp (using time() for the current timestamp).  It doesn't really matter if you use strings or integers for mktime()...it technically requires integers for the arguments but the strings will be cast as integers so no worries there...

Comment: You can use this code which takes leap years into account: [function.mktime.php#86086](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#86086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood what you're trying to do with the user so let me know if i was mistaken:

```
<?php
    $people = json_decode($data);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Users List</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php foreach ($people as $userName => $userInfo): ?>
    <div>
        <p><?php echo $userName; ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($userInfo as $label => $value): ?>
            <li><label><?php echo $label; ?></label> <?php echo $value; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Thrustmaster 2 levels of what? I don't see different levels of users in his example.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you are going to use this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

convert it to an array php can use.

```
<?php

$arr = json_decode('{"DOB":{"year": "1970", "month": "01", "day": "01"}}');
$year = $arr->DOB->year;
$month = $arr->DOB->month;
$day = $arr->DOB->day;

$today = date("Y-m-d"); 
$bday = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));

$today = new DateTime($today);
$bday = new DateTime($bday);
$age = $today->diff($bday)->y;

echo $age;


?>
```

This should work in PHP 5.3+ i believe.

Comment: Thanks! How would I use `json_decode()` with an external *.json file?

Comment: @tmcopeland i would say use fopen. Example can be found here: http://snippetdb.com/php/read-file-to-a-string

Comment: Does this look about right?  
`$json = fopen('/path/to/json.json', 'r');  
$people = json_decode($json, true);  
echo $people; // let's just make sure it works`

Comment: @tmcopeland - yea, but do var_dump instead of echo if you want to print the array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$str = '{"DOB":{"year": "1970","month": "01","day": "01"}}';
$obj = json_decode($str);
$obj->DOB->year = intval($obj->DOB->year);
$obj->DOB->month = intval($obj->DOB->month);
$obj->DOB->day = intval($obj->DOB->day);
$yearD  = date("Y") - $obj->DOB->year;
$monthD = date("m") - $obj->DOB->month;
$dayD   = date("d") - $obj->DOB->day;
if ($dayD < 0 || $monthD < 0)
    $yearD--;
echo "<pre>";
echo $yearD;
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Didnt take leap years into account. Just calculate no. of leap years, and add as many days.

And about your second question, you could visit this: [Convert JSON to HTML Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082928/convert-json-to-html-tree)